# non-analytic functions with arbitrary large derivatives

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, analytic-functions

This may be a trivial question but I can't see it immediately.

Suppose $\{a_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive reals. Does there exist a smooth function $f \in C^{\infty}([0,1])$ such that $\inf \partial^k f \ge a_k$ holds for all $k$?

Comment: Yes, see [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma).

Comment: the only difference is that here I want the bounds to hold over all the interval where as in Borel's lemma it holds only at one point of the interval. perhaps there is a simple way to extend the result?

Comment: Over all interval obviously not always. Just estimate $f(1)$ using Taylor formula at $0$ of high order.

Comment: Your comment is not the same as what you asked in the question. Your question asks for the $\sup$ to be lower bounded, for that you just need one point. Your comment asks for every point. Did you want $\inf$?

Comment: @fedja: I am feeling dense. I don't quite understand your comment. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @WillieWong $f(1)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\ge\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{k!}$ for every $n$, so if the series $\sum_k\frac{a_k}{k!}$ diverges, you are in trouble.

Comment: @fedja: thank you. (That's a great qualifying exam question.)